# How to retrieve users from firestore without creating a user collection?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vue-directives

How can i retrieve the users registered in firestore without having to create a collection and add those users to that collection?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firestore only contains the data that you put into it, and nothing else.

Comment: I guess you mean "the users registered in (my) Firebase (project)"

Comment: Yes, the users registered in my firebase project.

Answer (score 1):

With the Admin SDK you can use the [`listUsers`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth?authuser=0#list-users) method which:

> Retrieves a list of users (single batch only) with a size of
>   maxResults starting from the offset as specified by pageToken. This is
>   used to retrieve all the users of a specified project in batches.

You could, for example, use this method in a Cloud Function in order to retrieve the users. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users